# Office 365 installation on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, microsoft-office

Can Microsoft Office 365 be installed on Ubuntu 16.04? if it can be installed, how is it done?  I appreciate any help I can get on this.

Answer (score 1):

Office 365 is for macOS and Windows only; neither a single Linux distro nor wine offers support for it.

Install the appropriate Windows version in VirtualBox or VMWare.